# Почему нет запятой перед союзом И между односоставными предложениями?

Tags: пунктуация, и

В этих односоставных предложениях глаголы в повелительном наклонении имеют **разную форму**, значит, это **неоднородные** предложения?  Но почему тогда не ставится запятая перед союзом И?  В то же время в других подобных примерах запятая ставится.

**Примеры без запятой:**

1) **Не будем пугаться** бесконечных пустот и **давайте возрадуемся**! [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]

2) **Считайте** эти мои слова за увертюру к репетиции и **давайте** все-таки **начнем** с первого акта и попытаемся прогнать его вместе со вторым! [Николай Дежнев. В концертном исполнении (1993)]

**Спрячьте**, пожалуйста, ваше оружие и **давайте разберемся** спокойно. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Жук в муравейнике (1979)]

После рукопожатия Антон Павлович обратился ко мне со словами: ― **Садитесь и давайте принимать** больных. [M. E. Плотов. Большое сердце (1944)]

**Примеры с запятой:**

Так, **садитесь, и давайте разбираться.**

Так что мой совет: **кончайте разыгрывать** из себя простачка, и **давайте говорить** серьезно.

― **Успокойтесь, и давайте играть**.  [К. С. Станиславский. Работа актера над собой (1938)]

**Вопросы:**

Во всех предложениях правильно поставлены знаки препинания?

Может быть, на постановку запятой влияют и другие факторы?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Д. Э. Розенталю, [Параграф 104, пункт 2г](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxvii.html#sect104):

> 2. Запятая перед союзами *и*, *да* (в значении «и»), *или*, *либо* не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения:Источник: http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxvii.html#sect104
>
> ...
>
> г) выражены двумя вопросительными, или двумя восклицательными, или двумя побудительными предложениями, например: *Неужели впереди болото и путь к отступлению отрезан? Как часто мы встречались вместе и какие вели интересные беседы!* (Фурманов);

Также, в старом издании, [Параграф 30, пункты 3.2 и 3.3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133):

> 3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
>
> ...
>
> 2) побудительные предложения: *Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде!* (Фурманов) — объединяет побудительная интонация; *Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло!* — объединяет побудительная частица; *Да будет свято имя героя и память о нём сохранится в веках!* — объединяет побудительная частица;
>
> 3) восклицательные предложения: *Как он смешон и как глупы его выходки!* — объединяет восклицательная интонация; *Как часто мы собирались вместе и какие вели интересные беседы!*; *Сколько скрытого смысла в этих словах и какой отклик вызывают они у слушателей!*

Приведенные примеры **без запятой**, на мой взгляд, четко соответствуют 2г (побудительная форма).

Приведенные пример **с запятой** нарушают приведенное правило. Возможно, просто потому что нарушают. Возможно, потому что автор не вкладывал должной "побудительности" (простите за выражение) или восклицательной интонации. Как минимум, ни в одном из примеров **с запятой** нет восклицательного знака.

Постановка или непостановка запятой в данном случае может быть очень непростым решением, особенно, если неизвестен контекст и интонация.